# How can i configure different multiple vlan with dhcp server with a single ip subnetting

Tags: vlan

Hello every one out there!!

I got a issue i would like to share with you, expecting to have it sorted out.

I want o set up vlans on my network, in order to separat same department,which can be about 7 to 10 different Vlas.

lets say right now im using 192.168.1.0 network.

the thing is, i dont want to (and dont know) do subnetting stories and would like just to conntinue using the same subnettin (192.168.1.0).

I use Dhcp server to distribuite ip to the clients on that range.

So can anyone can help me on how can i configure the different vlas using dhcp server with a single subnet?? please

I thank you in advance. Sorry my english is not that good at all.

Mundjanga

Comment: Questions must be relevant to professional system administration. Server Fault is a site dedicated to professionals; novice questions are off-topic. Please see the Help Center for more information on topicality. The best advice we can give you is to hire a professional to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want VLAN's? There is no point in creating VLAN's if you use the same subnet across all of them.

I find it easiest to address the subnets to match the VLAN ID's:

```
VLAN 1  = 192.168.1.0/24
VLAN 2  = 192.168.2.0/24
VLAN 10 = 192.168.10.0/24
```

And so on. You then need a a router to allow traffic to be routed between the VLAN's.

However, your question indicates that you don't clearly understand VLAN's, so you need to clarify exactly why you want to implement VLAN's.